# How to change line color in d3js according to axis value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I want to change  color for this line chart if X > 100 I want it to turn "red"

Is there a way I can use condition within stroke color style based on value of X ?

http://jsfiddle.net/iamjeannie/b445svob/1/[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamjeannie/b445svob/1/)

```
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                  { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                  { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60},
                { "x": 120,  "y": 15},  { "x": 140, "y": 40},
                { "x": 160,  "y": 25},  { "x": 180, "y": 20},
                { "x": 200,  "y": 15},  { "x": 220, "y": 80},
                { "x": 240,  "y": 35},  { "x": 260, "y": 60}
               ];

 //This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                          .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("fill", "none");
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want a half of your path to have a different color? As far as I know this is not possible in the current version of SVG. Have you considered drawing multiple paths instead of one?

Comment: I guess the problem is that you provide the whole dataset at once (not the individual segments), thus it's hard to find the relevant subsegments in this approach. Two quick ideas that come to mind: (1) draw segments individually and build condition in `stroke` attribute or (2) apply a filter on the data and draw twice (as in @Oleg's comment above)

Comment: You can do it with gradients.  Define the gradient (which will actually have sharp changes in color) using `userSpaceOnUse` coordinates, based on the values on your axis at which you want to change color, then set the stroke of the path to use that gradient.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22031387/3128209) for a similar situation, but using a pattern, with further explanation and links to working examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's another way, maybe in some instances that might help:

All I do is split the data by using a `filter`:

```
var lineGraph1 = svgContainer.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData.filter(function(d) {
            return d.x <= 100;
        })))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
var lineGraph2 = svgContainer.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData.filter(function(d) {
            return d.x >= 100;
        })))
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
```

Comment: Looks like when d.x, it is on both lineGraph1 and lineGraph2.  Is that intentional?  (I'd recommend `d.x < 100` and `d.x >= 100`, for example).

Comment: Sure, you could tweak that a bit, you are right. Given the `stroke-width`, there will be an overlap in many cases, so I suggest you think about the order of the lines if you care about the color of the "overlays" (as order matters in svg). Thanks for the input @ryanm!

Answer (score 6):

I think you can achieve this by defining gradient for the line instead of styling it. 
Check out this solution here. 
[change color of line graph based on data (red for above threshold of say 0 , and blue for below 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805857/change-color-of-line-graph-based-on-data-red-for-above-threshold-of-say-0-and?noredirect=1#comment78569765_45805857)

I asked a very similar question yesterday and was able to get it working by reading D3 documentation and looking at some samples like this one 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3970883

```
svg.append("linearGradient")
               .attr("id", "line-gradient")
               .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
               .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))
               .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(2))
               .selectAll("stop")
               .data(
                      [
                       {offset: "100%", color: "blue"},
                       {offset: "100%", color: "red"},
                      ]
                    )
                .enter().append("stop")
                        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
                        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

Comment: This is the best answer if you like to keep your colors in CSS/SCSS like I do because you can change that data array to "class" instead of "color"/"stop-color" in the d3 code. It also doesn't segregate the data line like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick example that I've come up with:

Instead of a single path, let's use multiple lines.

We'll need to convert our data to have the following properties:

```
[
  {
    x1: currentX,
    y1: currentY,
    x2: nextX,
    y2: nextY
  },
  ...
]
```

Then we can draw them with a conditional `stroke` attribute based on data:

```
var lines = svgContainer.selectAll('line')
    .data(lineData)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.x1; })
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.y1; })
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.x2; })
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.y2; })
    .attr("stroke", function (d) {
        return (d.x > 50) ? 'red' : 'blue';
    })
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var lineData = [
        {"x": 1, "y": 5},
        {"x": 20, "y": 20},
                  { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                  { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60},
                { "x": 120,  "y": 15},  { "x": 140, "y": 40},
                { "x": 160,  "y": 25},  { "x": 180, "y": 20},
                { "x": 200,  "y": 15},  { "x": 220, "y": 80},
                { "x": 240,  "y": 35},  { "x": 260, "y": 60}
               ];
 
 //This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                          .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);

lineData = lineData.map(function (point, index, arr) {
    var next = arr[index + 1],
        prev = arr[index - 1];
    return {
        x: point.x,
        y: point.y,
        x1: point.x,
        y1: point.y,
        x2: (next) ? next.x : prev.x,
        y2: (next) ? next.y : prev.y
    };
});

var lines = svgContainer.selectAll('line')
        .data(lineData)
        .enter()
        .append('line')
        .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.x1; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.y1; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.x2; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.y2; })
        .attr("stroke", function (d) {
            return (d.x > 50) ? 'red' : 'blue';
        })
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to highlight a steep gradient in a different colour - I think your code gives me a start - here's my mod on your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q744d5bd/8/ ... thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to do this based on y value only?