# change color of line graph based on data (red for above threshold of say 0 , and blue for below 0)

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a problem to relay a graph based on the temperature of an object. 
The goal is to show portions of line graph in red where object's temperature is above 0 and blue when it is below 0

The graph is very similar to what is available here.
http://bl.ocks.org/pranitar/01305d9ad0eba73dbf80

I am able to change the color but cannot limit it to portions of line above or below the threshold. Instead, the whole graph is changing to red or blue when the values are input in real time. Please note, the graph is a dynamic graph which means data is given to graph in real time and the graph would keep shifting over time to show line graph.

Any help would be appreciated.

All I am using is JS and CSS. No additional framework suggestions, please.

Comment: (note that your example is using d3, which is not pure js/css). In the example, there is only one `<path>` element, what you want to do is split your data across different `<path>` with the proper css class so it gets the right color. (I don't know how to do it, but that's an idea)

Comment: Thanks @ValLeNain. I found the solution. Reading D3 documentation helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok after fiddling a lot (almost 4 hours) with d3, I figured out the solution to this situation. All I need to add was a gradient to the line and define colors and x/y values at which the gradient would change colors of the line.

Here is a sample of what I got after this change.

https://cdn.rawgit.com/jasmeetsinghbhatia/Roll-A-Ball-3D/2ce001fa/color%20graph%20for%20threshold%20speed%202.mov

Here is the sample code for same.

add to the css:

```
.graph .group {
          fill: none;
          stroke: url(#line-gradient);
          stroke-width: 1.5;
      }
```

add to the graph:

```
svg.append("linearGradient")
               .attr("id", "line-gradient")
               .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
               .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))
               .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(2))
               .selectAll("stop")
               .data(
                      [
                       {offset: "100%", color: "blue"},
                       {offset: "100%", color: "red"},
                      ]
                    )
                .enter().append("stop")
                        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
                        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

For a complete look at the graph in action:
https://github.com/jasmeetsinghbhatia/Roll-A-Ball-3D/blob/master/Assets/StreamingAssets/Tests/speed-ball-graph.html