# tickValues() in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am building my chart the next way: [see Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/21274/)

```
const margin = { top: 19, right: 16, bottom: 29, left: 16 };
const width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 96 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
const formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d.%m");

const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - 5, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
      .tickFormat(function (d) {
        //console.log(d)
        return formatTime(d);
}).ticks(ticksNumber);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

//establish the domain for x and y axes
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.health; }));

var axisNode = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x-axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);
```

But I can`t understand couple of things:

- As you can see on there is no data on 17.03 and 18.03 (it was
     weekends), so is there a way not to show the tick on xAxis if there
     is no data? I mean xAxis ticks should be
     ...15.03-16.03-19.03-20.03... No 17 and 18 on March.

  X axis tick values should be date in format DD.MM and only those
  which is represented in data array.

  Another words
     if I have 10 elements in my data array so 10 ticks should be (now 12
     ticks). I think than I should use **tickValues()** not **ticks()**,
     but totally do not understand how to implement it in right way.
- Also I got some date filters. And I also need to know is there a way
  to make next:

  All time we saw e.g. month chart (in jsfiddle case dates from 12.03
  to 23.03), the line which connect points is green. If we "filter"
  e.g. last week (19-25 of March) - filter I mean we pass to function
  which build chart startDate like 19-03-2018 and endDate 25-03-2018),
  so on the  chart this segment from 19.03 to 23.03 becomes e.g. red.
  Something like [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked and adjusted [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattbatman/nwq39e2y/40/). My edits aren't perfect, but I think they answer your questions and put you on the right track.

> Another words if I have 10 elements in my data array so 10 ticks
>   should be (now 12 ticks). I think than I should use tickValues() not
>   ticks(), but totally do not understand how to implement it in right
>   way.

Yep! You were on the right track. `tickValues()` will let you specify the exact ticks.

```
const tickValuesForAxis = data.map(d => parseDate(d.date));

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickValues(tickValuesForAxis)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
        return formatTime(d);
    });
```

> Also I got some date filters. And I also need to know is there a way
>   to make next:
>
> All time we saw e.g. month chart (in jsfiddle case dates from 12.03 to
>   23.03), the line which connect points is green. If we "filter" e.g. last week (19-25 of March) - filter I mean we pass to function which
>   build chart startDate like 19-03-2018 and endDate 25-03-2018), so on
>   the chart this segment from 19.03 to 23.03 becomes e.g. red. Something
>   like

I took a hint from [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026625/how-to-change-line-color-in-d3js-according-to-axis-value). The basic idea here is to create separate lines, each filtered to the data you want it to be colored for.

The implementation in my forked fiddle just gives you an idea of what can be done. I think you can make it much more dynamic.

```
const splitDate = data[6].date;

svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", line(data.filter(d => d.date <= splitDate )))
        .attr("stroke",'#35b37e')
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");

svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", line(data.filter(d => d.date >= splitDate )))
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
```

Full JS:

```
let data = [
  {"date": "2018-03-12", "health": 93, "risks": 10, "incidents": 0},
  {"date": "2018-03-13", "health": 80, "risks": 5, "incidents": 2},
  {"date": "2018-03-14", "health": 40, "risks": 1, "incidents": 5},
  {"date": "2018-03-15", "health": 90, "risks": 5, "incidents": 6},
  {"date": "2018-03-16", "health": 12, "risks": 12, "incidents": 7},
  {"date": "2018-03-19", "health": 100, "risks": 11, "incidents": 1},
  {"date": "2018-03-20", "health": 93, "risks": 8, "incidents": 5},
  {"date": "2018-03-21", "health": 64, "risks": 9, "incidents": 6},
  {"date": "2018-03-22", "health": 55, "risks": 7, "incidents": 12},
  {"date": "2018-03-23", "health": 100, "risks": 9, "incidents": 12},
]

const ticksNumber = data.length;
var tickValues = data.map(function (d) { return moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD.MM'); });

const margin = { top: 19, right: 16, bottom: 29, left: 16 };
const width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 96 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
const formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d.%m");

const tickValuesForAxis = data.map(d => parseDate(d.date));

const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - 5, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickValues(tickValuesForAxis)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
        return formatTime(d);
    });

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

let line = d3.line()
      .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function (d) { return y(d.health); })
      .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

// gridlines in x axis function
function make_x_gridlines() {
      return d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(ticksNumber)
}

let svg = d3.select('#viz')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

//establish the domain for x and y axes
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.health; }));

var axisNode = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x-axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

axisNode.selectAll('text').each(function () {
      if (this.textContent && !tickValues.includes(this.textContent)) {
        this.classList.add("day-off");
      }
});

// add the X gridlines
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr('stroke', '#d2e3ed')
    .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.1)
    .attr("transform", "translate(-0.5," + height + ")")
    .call(
      make_x_gridlines()
        .tickSize(-height)
        .tickFormat("")
);


// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select('body').append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("box-shadow", "0 0 0 1px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.24)");

/*  svg.append('path').datum(data)
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('d', line)
      .attr('stroke', '#35b37e')
      .attr('stroke-width', '2')
      .attr('fill', 'none'); */

const splitDate = data[6].date;

svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", line(data.filter(d => d.date <= splitDate )))
        .attr("stroke",'#35b37e')
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");

svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", line(data.filter(d => d.date >= splitDate )))
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");

 svg.selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr('stroke', '#35b37e')
      .attr('stroke-width', '2')
      .attr('fill', '#f7f8f9')
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.health); })
      .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
      .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut)
      .style("opacity", 0);

    function handleMouseOver(d, i) {
      d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
      div.html(moment(d.date).format("DD MMM YYYY") + "<br/>" +
        "Health: " + d.health + "<br/>" +
        "Risks: " + d.risks + "<br/>" +
        "Incidents: " + d.incidents)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 60) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 115) + "px");
    }

    function handleMouseOut(d, i) {
      d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0);
      div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that is what I need